# Filter Both Parent And Child Collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<Employee>`:

The `Employee` class with a `List<Address>` collection

The `Address` class has a `City` property

So the `List<Employee` could be populated like this:

```
NAME | ADDRESS[0]        | ADDRESS[1]
Bob  | Main St, Boston   | River St, Chicago
Mary | Park St, Seattle  | Beach St, Miami
```

The following linq returns all the `Employee` objects that have an Address object where the `City` is "Boston".

```
employeeList.Where(x => x.Addresses.Any(y => y.City == "Boston")).ToList<Employee>();
```

Although this correctly filters the employees that have Boston addresses, their other non-Boston address are also returned. Using the above table to illustrate, the only employee returned is Bob (which is correct) but both of his addresses are also returned. I would like only his Boston address to be returned.

Is this possible using linq or will I need to do some additional manual filtering to filter the child collection too?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something like the following:

```
employeeList.Where(x => x.Addresses.Any(y => y.City == "Boston"))
        .Select(z => new Employee()
{
   Name = z.Name,
   Addresses = z.Addresses.Where(a => a.City == "Boston").ToList<Address>()    
}).ToList<Employee>();
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
employeeList.Where(x => x.Addresses
                    .Contains(x.Addresses.Where(y => y.City == "Boston")
                        .FirstOrDefault())).ToList<Employee>();
```